# When I search my iOS app through browser I'm seeing this **WEA.AppPages.DesignedFor** on AppStore website

Tags: ios, app-store

Can someone give me information about this below snap [image]

I have search my app through Safari browser on appStore website but I came to see below snap, I don't have any idea about this can someone get me some info about this(if you go to appstore website on browser and search for any app you will be able see this), thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source:

```
"WEA.AppPages.CTA.MacAppStore.App":"Mac App Store",
"WEA.AppPages.Category":"Category",
"WEA.AppPages.Compatibility":"Compatibility",
"WEA.AppPages.Copyright":"Copyright",
"WEA.AppPages.CustomerReviews.Title":"Ratings and Reviews",
"WEA.AppPages.CustomersAlsoBought.Title":"You May Also Like",
"WEA.AppPages.Description.Header":"Description",
"WEA.AppPages.DesignedFor":"**WEA.AppPages.DesignedFor**",
"WEA.AppPages.DeveloperResponse":"Developer Response",
"WEA.AppPages.DeveloperWebsite":"Developer Website"
```

It looks like a UI bug on Apple's side. It looks like they're expecting that string to come from somewhere and its not getting populated.

It's not just your app. Its App Store wide when viewed from the web.

Answer (score 0):

If your App is not going to be available in the Mac Appstore do the following:

- Login into AppstoreConnect
- Go to the affected App
- Go to price and availability
- Un-Check the option to distribute apps in the Mac
- Wait a couple of minutes and it will disappear

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3ag1.png)