# **WEA.AppPages.DesignedFor** appears on Appstore website

Tags: ios, app-store

today when I checked my app's page on appstore website I realized a message was added in my app page `**WEA.AppPages.DesignedFor**`
what is that mean???
[image]

Comment: Same concern, anyone please help to explain?

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64384620/when-i-search-my-ios-app-through-browser-im-seeing-this-wea-apppages-designed